# Javascript network error as a string

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

When there is an error on XMLHttpRequest, how do I get the actual error text in Javascript? It gets output to the console but it seems impossible to get as a string.

Example:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('get', 'http://nowhere/', true);
req.send();
```

This causes an error in the console:

```
GET http://nowhere/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

How to get this with Javascript?

---

**Edit:** To clarify, I am interested in *network errors*, i.e. when there is no response for some other reason. An example is when the host name cannot be resolved. Another example is when the connection is refused. Another example is when there is a CORS error.

Answer (score -1):

To get the response from a server, use the responseText or responseXML property of the XMLHttpRequest object.

```
alert(req.responseText);
```

responseText - get the response data as a string.

responseXML - get the response data as XML data.

To detect if ajax request has an error check the req.readyState is equal to 4 and if the req.status is less than 200 then get the error by **req.statusText**.

Comment: This doesn't help with network errors, such as when the host name is not resolved, or there is a cors error, etc.

Comment: Try reading this maybe this could help. (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp)

Comment: I'm not getting any responseText. The URL is to http://nowhere/ and that server doesn't exist. There is no way to get the response from the server - there is no server. Here is a jsFiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/wvy4c9Lw/